# Fetch text box value of a tab of Dialogue box of Ckeditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am trying to fetch text box value of a tab of dialogue box of ckeditor using below code.

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev )
{
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

    if ( dialogName == 'image' )
    {
      dialogDefinition.addContents({
        id : 'uploadTab',
        label : 'Upload',
        elements : [
          {
            type: 'text',
            id: 'uploadField',
            label: 'Search images',     
          }
        ]
      })

      var inputField = dialogDefinition.getContents('uploadTab').get('uploadField');

      inputField.onChange = function(){
        console.log(inputField.getValue());
      };
    }
});
```

But I am getting error `Uncaught TypeError: dialogDefinition.getContents(...).get is not a function`.